# Why does TreeWalker currentNode default to root node?

Tags: javascript, dom-traversal

When constructing a TreeWalker, why does the [currentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/currentNode) point to the root, even though it may not pass filter criteria?

I would have expected it to be null, until I call nextNode, so that I can see if the root is passing filter criteria passed to it.

I guess it's the way its designed, I just don't quite understand the reason. It doesn't fit my use case of finding all elements with a particular attribute set, including the root.  If I go up to the parent of the root, I'm including siblings I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current node](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-treewalker-currentnode) does not represent the result of the last method call, but it denotes the current state of the walk, the node from which the next step is made. It must never be null, and indeed might be a node that would not pass the filter - it can be set arbitrarily (manually, not only by the step methods).

Only the return values of all the method calls will be filtered nodes, and those can be `null`.

> It doesn't fit my use case of finding all elements with a particular attribute set, including the root.

Using the [`parentNode` method](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-treewalker-parentnode) should eventually get you to the root node if it matches the filter, or `null` otherwise.

Comment: I think the design of TreeWalker is flawed, but maybe I'm missing something.  Anyway I've decided to use my own customized implementation.  Might be slower than native but it works.  I'll accept the answer as seems the only option with the standard implementation.

Comment: @dave: In fact I have the feeling that the [`nextNode` algorithm](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-treewalker-nextnode) as currently in the spec is buggy as well, since it never ascends the tree.

Answer (score 0):

`currentNode` points to the root, because then it can recursively traverse the document subtree, calling each `childNode` as the root of its own tree. It is not necessarily pointing to the root of the document, just the `root` node the tree was created with. See [`tree traversal`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Comment: I'm setting the root to an element within the document.  I don't understand the reason why it has been designed so that the root i've specified isn't included as part of TreeWalker's traversal.  It would have been trivial for nextNode to check if the currentNode is null and try to process it.

Comment: if you set the root to null like you suggested you expected, how can you call nextNode? The nextNode of a null root would be null

Comment: I'm *not* setting the root to null.  In the constructor, I am passing a non-null node.  I would have expected nextNode to test that node and return it if it passes the filter i've specified.  So, I'm expecting that *currentNode* is null immediately after TreeWalker is constructed, but not the read-only root.

Comment: If you are setting that to a non-null node, then calling nextNode wouldn't affect the root node passed to the method, it would affect the node your rootNode is pointing to.

Comment: My point is nextNode won't return the root node, even if it passes the filter.  I'm trying to understand the rational behind the design of TreeWalker